# FFmpeg scale image do not use command way

Tags: c, ffmpeg

**I want scale a image with ffmpeg, not the command way,**

so what is the steps?

I try use `"libswscale/swscale.h"`

```
int sws_scale(struct SwsContext *c,const uint8_t *const     srcSlice[],const int    rcStride[],int  srcSliceY,int   srcSliceH,uint8_t *const    dst[],const int dstStride[] )
```

but need get the image info, like width, height, formate etc;

how can I get these infomation and what next step do?

Comment: In what format is your image currently stored? Is it an AVFrame? Is it a file no disk in JPEG format? Something else?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje , I do not know what format ,  just know it is a image file   on disk。

Comment: You'll have to learn how to decode the image from disk into an AVFrame struct. There's many examples on how to use ffmpeg (libavformat, libavcodec) for decoding videos and images. Then, the size/format will be in AVFrame->width/height and AVFrame->format.